# Derivative of a random variable w.r.t. its parameter

Tags: probability

Suppose we have a random variable defined as:
$$T_x:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}:\omega\mapsto 1 \text{ with probability } \frac{1}{2} + \frac{x}{2}; \omega \mapsto 0 \text{ with probability } \frac{1}{2}-\frac{x}{2},$$
where $\Omega$ is a probability space and $x\in [-1, 1]$ is a parameter of $T_x$.

I wonder how to compute $\partial T_x(\omega) /\partial x$?

We could explicitly write out the probability mass function (pmf) of $T_x$ in this case as it is simply a Bernoulli random variable. But differentiating the pmf of $T_x$ w.r.t. $x$ is not quite the same as differentiating $T_x$ w.r.t. $x$, is it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\Omega=[0,1]$. This is just one possibility... In this case, our random variable, $T_x$, if $x$ is given, is a function of $\omega\in [0,1]$ as shown below:

[image]

If this is the case then $P(T_x=1)=\frac12+\frac x2$ and $P(T_x=0)=1-\left(\frac12+\frac x2\right)=\frac12-\frac x2$, as it is prescribed.

If $\omega\in[0,1]$ is given then $T_x(\omega)$ as a function of $x$ is like this

[image]

The derivative of this function at a given $\omega$ with respect to $x$ is constant zero.

The pmf of $T_x$ if $x$ is fixed:

$$F_{T_x}(u)=P(T_x<u)=\begin{cases}
0&\text{ if }& u\leq 0\\
\frac12-\frac x2&\text{ if }& 0<u\leq 1\\
1&\text{ if }& 1<u
\end{cases}.$$

The derivative of the function above with respect to $x$ is

$$\frac{\partial F_x(u)}{\partial x}=
\begin{cases}
0&\text{ if }& u\leq 0\\
-\frac 12&\text{ if }& 0<u\leq 1\\
0&\text{ if }& 1<u
\end{cases}$$

which function does not have to do with

$$\frac{\partial T_x}{\partial x} =0.$$

Comment: Thanks for helping. I have a question, though. About the first figure, even if we constrain ourselves to the case where $\Omega = [0, 1]$, as you said, $T_x(\omega)$ does not necessarily have to look like what you have in Fig. 1. As long as the set of $\omega$ on which $T_x$ is 1 has measure $1/2 + x/2$ then we should be good. In these infinitely many alternative cases, the fact that $\partial T_x/\partial x =0$ may not always be true, right?

Comment: Also, given Fig. 1, shouldn't the $1$ area of $T_x$ in Fig. 2 be $0$ and the $0$ area $1$?

Comment: You are right: there are infinitely many cases to model $\Omega$. My example is just a counterexanple of the claim that the such derivatives have some interesting general relationship.

Comment: I see. One last question, is there no way to deduce some more generic expressions for $\partial T_x/\partial x$? Thanks!